# Submitting multiple forms with one button, not working because of class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set up a system on an ecommerce site's basket page that will update the quantity of an add-on product if the main product quantity is updated. I was able to get this working when I only had one main product in the basket, but when there's two, it doesn't.

There's only one of the addon product so I have a different form set up for it, but thousands of the main products so they share the same one. Each main product has a update quantity button, and I'm able to update the quantity for the addon field based on the quantity entered. Since I'm testing with more than one main product now, I switch from ids to classes.

An example is -

Main Product "A" and "B" have this-

```
     <form method="post" action="/basket.html" class="updateQtyForm">
```

Addon Product "C" has this-

```
     <form method="post" action="/basket.html" id="updateQtyCForm">
```

My jquery that I had working for if there's only one main product and the add on product is -

```
    $("#submitBtn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post($("#updateQtyCForm").attr("action"), $("#updateQtyCForm").serialize(), 
        function() {
            $.post($("#updateQtyForm").attr("action"), $("#updateQtyForm").serialize(),
            function() {
                 window.location.href = "/basket.html";
            }
            );
        });
    });
```

The code that I'm trying to get to work for more than one main product is -

```
    $(".submitBtn").click(function(e) {      
         e.preventDefault();
         $.post($("#updateCQtyForm").attr("action"), $("#updateCQtyForm").serialize(), 
         function() {
             $.post($(".updateQtyForm").attr("action"), $(".updateQtyForm").serialize(), 
             function() {
                 window.location.href = "/basket.html";
              }
              )
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the form where the button was clicked on. Assuming each form has it's own submit button, you can do the following:

```js
    $(".submitBtn").click(function(e) {      
         e.preventDefault();
         // targets the respective form based on which submit was clicked on
         var form = $(e.target).parents('form');
         $.post($("#updateCQtyForm").attr("action"), $("#updateCQtyForm").serialize(), 
         function() {
             $.post(form.attr("action"), form.serialize(), 
             function() {
                 window.location.href = "/basket.html";
              }
              )
         });
    });
```